# Determine which java 2d Rectangle edge (top/left/etc) an angle points to (from center)

Tags: java, java-2d

I have two Rectangles (call them A and B) on a game map and I've calculated the angle from the center of B to A. I have code that spawns a third (C) and "shoots" it from B to A. The problem is that in my game, two of these game elements should never overlap (they have collision code normally) so the "shooting" code is stopped - spawning C on top doesn't work logistically.

My solution (tell me if there's a better one) is to spawn the third rectangle *next to* the edge of the parent - but for the UI to function properly, it needs to always spawn off the edge of the parent that faces rectangle A.

I know the center coordinates for rectangle B, I know the angle (can be in radians or degrees) from B to A, how can I determine which side (left, top, right, bottom) the angle would point at?

Answer (score 0):

Think of the square lying on the unit circle with its center at the origin. Then figure out if Java behaves like JavaScript which is backwards from standard trigenometry. (pi/2 is straight down in JS whereas it is straight up in standard trig). Rectangle objects also have boundary and intersection methods which may help.

The graphic a little down this page may help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle

Answer (score 0):

When I've written games with collision engines like this, and needed projectile launching behavior, there's been a couple different approaches I've taken.

First, I've maintained a reference to the entity that fired the projectile. Then in the collision detection method, I've compared against this reference.

Another option, which may be preferable, is to instead associate the entities to a "Faction". This could be modeled as an enum. Then the collision detection code could check to ensure the two entities are not in the same faction. You could also use a mapping to determine which factions collide with each other. For instance, you could have "Hostile", "Neutral", and "Player" factions and have the player faction entities not collide with Neutral, etc. It would depend on the "business rules" of your game.

If you do this, you can spawn the projectile anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that `angle` is the angle from center of `B` to center of `A`, given in radians in the interval -pi..pi, then the following should do what you want (remember that like @Jared suggested, positive angles are down rather than up):

```
double halfPi = Math.PI/2;
double theta = Math.atan2(B.height, B.width);
if (angle >= theta+halfPi || angle <= -theta-halfPi) {
    // left side
} else if (angle >= theta) {
    // bottom side
} else if (angle >= -theta) {
    // right side
} else {
    // top side
}
```